# LayoutInflater and View, a weird thing

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-dialog

I have noticed a weird thing in Android. I can't use EditText functions like `getText()` - for example, when I type:

```
final EditText txtUser = (EditText) inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_dialog, null).findViewById(R.id.txtUsername);
```

And when I use:

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_dialog, null);
final EditText txtUser = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.txtUsername);
```

everything works fine. I noticed that `inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_dialog, null);` returns view, so I don't understand why I can't use `getText()` function when I don't use a view instance.

Thank You.

Comment: what did you not understand ?

Comment: Possibly because View doesn't have that method.

Answer (score 0):

You are inflating Custom dialog. So in order to use its component, you first need to initialise it as View.
If you want to use method of other class, you must create instance of that class first.
In first code you have not declared `inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_dialog,null);` as type `View`, so compiler doesn't know what you are intended to use.

But in second code, you have declared your `inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_dialog,null);` as `View` type so you can use method that is applicable for `View` class.